# Write document in Hindi using pdflatex

Tags: pdftex, texworks, hindi

I want to write in Hindi using a `.tex` file and pdfLaTeX.

I searched on net, it gives examples of XeTeX and LuaTeX.

Using TeXworks, even if I select LuaLaTeX and try following code :

```
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{fontspec}
 \setmainfont{Times New Roman}
 \newfontface{\hindi}{Script=Devanagri}{Lohit Devanagri}
 Hello welcome !!!

 {\hindi} बदले सदस्य वर्णित आंतरजाल होभर हमारी गटकउसि और्४५० विवरन लक्ष्य यायेका प्रेरना सकती हुआआदी भेदनक्षमता विकासक्षमता शीघ्र होभर नाकर वेबजाल निर्माता पहोच। कर्य हिंदी स्थापित कार्यलय अधिकांश पहेला सुना खरिदने एसेएवं बेंगलूर परिवहन अन्तरराष्ट्रीयकरन देखने उनको पेदा वर्णन रहारुप विकसित शीघ्र जोवे संपादक सहायता रहारुप पहोच। लिये भारतीय आशाआपस सिद्धांत दर्शाता व्रुद्धि निरपेक्ष वर्ष संसाध भाषा सक्षम दिनांक विश्वास मुख्य दुनिया व्याख्यान लाभो करती विश्व प्रतिबध स्वतंत्र केन्द्रित वर्णन कोहम दोषसके वातावरण कम्प्युटर जागरुक विकसित व्रुद्धि करते मुख्य वर्णन पत्रिका लाभान्वित स्वतंत्रता रचना हीकम कार्य दुनिया सभिसमज बीसबतेबोध कारन करता। मुश्किल कम्प्युटर कार्यकर्ता आपको विशेष ऎसाजीस लाभान्वित क्षमता दिनांक दे

\end{document}
```

I am getting the following error :

> "!  Package fontspec Error: The font "Script=Devanagri" cannot be found."

I am not able to understand what exactly is wrong.

Comment: Is there any specific reason you want to use pdflatex and not xe- or lualatex?

Comment: I have other language support also e.g German, Chinese, Japanese which works as expected using pdfLatex and generates PDF document. So, a general code which suits all language would be more maintainable. That's the reason I wanted to use pdfLatex. But if it does not support I will have to handle it for xe/lua latex

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is wrong. You are using braces instead of bracket, and you have a typo. Also with current version of fontspec the option can/should be behind the font name. Try

```
\newfontface{\hindi}{Lohit Devanagri}[Script=Devanagari]
```

(untested as I don't have the font).

Be aware that Devanagari is a bit problematic with lualatex. You need at least a very current system.

Comment: Yes, I got the typo which was causing the problem Instead of Devanagari I had written - Devanagri. Also, the syntax for specifying script [] instead of {} helped me. Thanks for the pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Install the font from [here](https://www.fontsc.com/font/lohit-devanagari).

Use XeLaTeX for creating the PDF document.

The following code worked for me :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont[Script=Devanagari]{Lohit Devanagari}

\begin{document}

\section{संस्कृतम्}

जीवनस्य लक्ष्यमेव संस्कृतस्य वर्धनम्

बदले सदस्य वर्णित आंतरजाल होभर हमारी गटकउसि और्४५० विवरन लक्ष्य यायेका प्रेरना सकती हुआआदी भेदनक्षमता विकासक्षमता शीघ्र होभर नाकर वेबजाल निर्माता पहोच। कर्य हिंदी स्थापित कार्यलय अधिकांश पहेला सुना खरिदने एसेएवं बेंगलूर परिवहन अन्तरराष्ट्रीयकरन देखने उनको पेदा वर्णन रहारुप विकसित शीघ्र जोवे संपादक सहायता रहारुप पहोच। लिये भारतीय आशाआपस सिद्धांत दर्शाता व्रुद्धि निरपेक्ष वर्ष संसाध भाषा सक्षम दिनांक विश्वास मुख्य दुनिया व्याख्यान लाभो करती विश्व प्रतिबध स्वतंत्र केन्द्रित वर्णन कोहम दोषसके वातावरण कम्प्युटर जागरुक विकसित व्रुद्धि करते मुख्य वर्णन पत्रिका लाभान्वित स्वतंत्रता रचना हीकम कार्य दुनिया सभिसमज बीसबतेबोध कारन करता। मुश्किल कम्प्युटर कार्यकर्ता आपको विशेष ऎसाजीस लाभान्वित क्षमता दिनांक दे

\subsection{कोऽम्}

\end{document}
```